# How do I use and & or in a TFS 2010 query

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have created the following query:

```
AndOr Field           Operator   Value
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
      Team Project    =          @Project
And   Area Path       Under      MyProject 
And   Iteration Path  Under      MyProject\Iteration 5
And   Work Item Type  =          User Story
Or    Work Item Type  =          Task
```

After I run the query, I see all the workitems in the results, even if they are under Iteration 4, Iteration3, etc.

I only expected to see all User Story and Task items under MyProject\Iteration5.

The way I added my Iteration 5 was to go to Areas and Iterations and creating it.  Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to only see the user stories and tasks you will need to group these clauses together in the query editor.

From within the Visual Studio IDE, edit your query, ensure the two lines refering to work item type are adjacent to each other and last in the list of clauses e.g.

- 1       Team Project    =        @Project
- 2 And      Iteration       Under    \MyIteration
- 3 And      Work Item Type  =        User Story
- 4 Or       Work Item Type  =        Task

Highlight both the Work Item Type clauses (items 3 and 4) and right click and select 'Group Clauses'.  Execute your query.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are a genius, you understood the question, you knew the answer, and you answered it so I could follow. THANKS A MILLION.